# how to use if else condition for python dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python.I have dictionary variable like this:

```
vs={'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.254, 'pos': 0.746, 'compound': 0.8316}
```

i want to use if else condition and perform following operations, How to do this

```
positive sentiment: compound score >= 0.05
neutral sentiment: (compound score > -0.05) and (compound score < 0.05)
negative sentiment: compound score <= -0.05
```

```py
vs = {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.254, 'pos': 0.746, 'compound': 0.8316}
for k, v in vs.items():
    if k['compound'] >= 0.5:
        print('positive')
```

Error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: What is this negative and positive sentiment?

Comment: @MihranThalhath Don't need negative and positive sentiment. Just want to find if compound value is > then 0.05 its positive and same as remaining.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please explain it little more and what value you need

Comment: @MihranThalhath I hope this code will help...

Answer (score 2):

If you need to just check the value of compound and you have only one dictionary, you can do this

```
if vs['compound'] >= 0.05:
    print('positive')
elif vs['compound'] <= -0.05:
    print('negative')
else:
    print('neutral')
```